# Spurious requests, certificate auditors?

Tags: apache, http, ssl

In the last few days I've seen lots of POST requests to many of the domains I own hitting the following paths:

```
/ct/v1/sct-gossip
/ct/v1/sct-feedback
/.well-known/ct/v1/sct-feedback
/.well-known/ct/v1/sth-pollination
/.well-known/ct/v1/collected-sct-feedback
/.well-known/ct/v1/sct-gossip
/topleveldir/subdir/research-feedback
```

Is this someone trying to do something dubious?

I found the following document which suggests this might be something to do with certificate auditors although I am not sure what! All of my websites are fronted by Cloudflare which provides the SSL certs so I would really expect Cloudflare to handle any such requests.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-trans-gossip-00

Any thoughts would be appreciated :-)

Comment: i got that too. Anyone can answer the question? I also want to know

Comment: And me too. Also interested in what these are. Only unique thing to my situation is that i am about to change the SSL cert on the domain in af few days because the old one runs out...

Comment: Same here :v I  just changed my certificates from letsencrypt to wildcard @ gandi like 2 weeks ago, and theses notifications started 3 days ago..

Comment: It seems to be related with https://www.net.in.tum.de/projects/gino/index.html#internet-wide-scans

Comment: Thanks @QuentinL.D. that link does indeed list the IPs from which the requests came. As these requests resulted in errors I received over 100 emails from my server within the space of a few minutes! I guess it's nothing to worry about, aside from the email SPAM...

Comment: Thanks @QuentinL.D. I also received POST from such address. Maybe you could turn your comment into an answer to make it more visible.

Comment: I just posted an answer with details, thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After investigations, the requests comes from https://net.in.tum.de/projects/gino/index.html#internet-wide-scans

They are conducting Internet measurements to find Certificate Transparency Gossip Endpoints.

You can ask them to blacklist your domain/IP just by sending an email to scans@net.in.tum.de

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is a knwon security protocol for certificate chains.

Comment: Can you elaborate? *What* is a known security protocol?

Answer (score 1):

https://ct.grahamedgecombe.com/

has:
Signed Tree Head gossip

Two API endpoints are provided for exchanging STH gossip:

```
/ct/v1/sth-gossip, which implements draft-linus-trans-gossip-ct-01.
/.well-known/ct/v1/sth-pollination, which implements draft-ietf-trans-gossip-00.
```

Both return all the STHs observed over the last hour, so there is little point in querying them more than once every 30 minutes. If you use one of these endpoints, I'd appreciate being able to fetch gossip from your monitor in return. In particular, the /ct/v1/sth-gossip endpoint doesn't support exchanging gossip in both directions. Get in touch with me if you want to organise this.
Signed Certificate Timestamp gossip

An experimental API endpoint is provided for submitting SCT gossip:

```
/ct/v1/sct-feedback, which implements draft-ietf-trans-gossip-00.
```

The monitor checks that the corresponding entries are included in the log after the log's Maximum Merge Delay has elapsed. Although the results of this check are stored in the database, they are not currently displayed in the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; - very likely malicious traffic or check that the ips fall within the range posted by @QuentinL.D

The `.well-known` urls are likely attempts to exploit some **possible** from https://www.letsencrypt.org. Or more likely misconfigured web servers. I say possible b/c i have not heard of any issues with letsencrypt, if you're not using `letsencrypt` then i would consider this malicious traffic. A normal request from `letsencrypt`/`certbot`[1] would look similar to:

`127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2017:22:21:02 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/2VJSAGWTQ3l14rkSa7MTbVYKiwPEXvrx2T1BdQpOVhc HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Let's Encrypt validation server; +https://www.letsencrypt.org)" "-"`

Note that mine states 127.0.0.1 b/c i route these requests with haproxy locally to a distinct port/backend and not to the web servers in the cluster.

1 - https://github.com/certbot/certbot

I too see these in my web server logs, which will never host a letsencrypt `.well-known` folder, which is why i (briefly) explained my setup above

I realize this is not an exact answer to your question, but hopefully this helps.

EDIT: The IPs hitting these urls are within the rage posted by @QuentinL.D, didn't notice that comment first, thanks for the link.